# lots of nan data when convert pointcloud2 to pcl::PointXYZ

Tags: ros, gazebo, kinect, data, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI all, I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTI with ROS Indigo. Then I simulate kinect in Gazebo:

```
 <xacro:macro name="kinect_camera" params="name parent *origin">
  <xacro:kinect_camera_model name="${name}" parent="${parent}">
    <xacro:insert_block name="origin" />
  </xacro:kinect_camera_model>
  
  <gazebo reference="${name}_depth_frame">
    <sensor type="depth" name="${name}">
      <update_rate>20</update_rate>
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>${60 * M_PI/180.0}</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>480</height>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.05</near>
          <far>3</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="${name}_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>20</updateRate>
        <imageTopicName>${name}/rgb/image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>${name}/rgb/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <depthImageTopicName>${name}/depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
        <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>${name}/depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
        <pointCloudTopicName>${name}/depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
        <pointCloudCutoff>0.5</pointCloudCutoff>
        <frameName>${name}_depth_optical_frame</frameName>
        <distortion_k1>0.0</distortion_k1>
        <distortion_k2>0.0</distortion_k2>
        <distortion_k3>0.0</distortion_k3>
        <distortion_t1>0.0</distortion_t1>
        <distortion_t2>0.0</distortion_t2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</xacro:macro>
```

Then I convert pointcloud2 to pcl::PointXYZ
follow the link:[pcl/overview](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview)

> 3.1 For a subscriber that receives pcl::PointCloud objects directly:

**My code:**

```
void callback(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr& position)  
{  
     const char *path="/home/lin/Desktop/distance.dat";  
     ofstream file(path);  
     for(int i=0; i<307200;i++)
 {    
      cout << "(x,y,z) = " << position -> points[i] << std::endl;  
      file << position -> points[i];  
  }  
}  


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    ros::init(argc, argv, "distance_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    std::string topic = nh.resolveName("camera/depth/points");
    uint32_t queue_size = 1;

    // create a templated subscriber
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> > (topic, queue_size, callback);

        ros::Rate r(0.1);
        while(nh.ok()){
        
          ros::spinOnce(); 
          r.sleep();
         
        }

}
```

`
**I get lots of NAN data , I just want to know when convert pointcloud2 to pcl::PointXYZ, it will remove nan data automatically or I need to filter it.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207245/lots-of-nan-data-when-convert-pointcloud2-to-pcl::pointxyz/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this works fine, also please check PCL library in your CmakeLists.txt.

```
void callback(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr& inputCloud )
{
   
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr outputCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    vector<int> indices;
    pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(*inputCloud,*outputCloud, indices);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) with karma: 214 on 2015-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You still need to remove the NaN values from the point cloud. You can do that in the callback like this:

```
void callback (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_in_)
{

        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> filtered_cloud_ = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    //remove NaN points from the cloud
    std::vector<int> indices;
    pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(*cloud_in_,*filtered_cloud_, indices);

}
```

---

Originally posted by [epoxi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22069/epoxi/) with karma: 11 on 2015-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-04-17**:
thanks for your help, but it still have error.